# Alarm manager Not triggering with correct time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I know this is most common thread in SO but i didn't find any answer for my question . I want to trigger dynamic broadcast receiver at particular time. For this i am using below code

```
public void method1() {
    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            doTASK();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.XXXX.wakeup"));
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent("com.xxxx.wakeup"), 0);
    am = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

    setAlarmManagerObject();
}
```

And setAlarmManagerObject() method is here

```
   public void setAlarmManagerObject() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cal.set(year, month, day
            , com.XXXX.Constants.AlarmHour
            , com.xxxx.Constants.AlarmMinute
            , com.xxxx.AlarmSecond);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

My problem is that when i used AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP it wake up when device is off. I don't want this property in my app. So i used AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, but with ELAPSED_REALTIME alarm manager is not triggering. I want that my alarm manager trigger exact at same time. If device is off or sleep condition then alarm manager will also off after device wake up.It should trigger at exact time. Any help will really appreciated.

Comment: I am also looking for solution,?

Comment: I have replied with an answer. Please check.

Comment: ELAPSED_REALTIME : Fires the pending intent based on the amount of time since the device was booted, but doesn't wake up the device. The elapsed time includes any time during which the device was asleep. You might want to try RTC in place of RTC_WAKEUP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this:-

```
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP (or AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME), 
 SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + Constants.DELAY_IN_MILLIS, 
 pendingIntent);
```

You can calculate DELAY_IN_MILLIS which is time delay in milliseconds from current system time.

For repeating alarm you can have code something like this:-

```
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
 SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + Constants.DELAY_IN_MILLIS, 
 Constants.ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS, 
 pendingIntent);
```

Comment: what is the problem are you facing?